# Invalid prop `style` of type `number`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Animated } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
class Fade extends React.Component {
     Fade.propTypes = {
 visible:PropTypes.bool,
 style:PropTypes.object,
 children:PropTypes.any
};
  render() {
    const { visible, style, children, ...rest } = this.props;
    const combinedStyle = [containerStyle, style];
    return (
      <Animated.View style={this.state.visible ? combinedStyle : containerStyle} {...rest}>
        {this.state.visible ? children : null}
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
```

I got the following errors:
Invalid prop `style` of type `number` supplied to `Fade`, expected `object`
Invalid prop `style` of type `number` supplied to `Fade`, expected `object`

Comment: can you please include the code for the parent class where you hold this component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `style: PropTypes.object` to `ViewPropTypes.style` like below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
 Animated,
 ViewPropTypes # <= declare
} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Fade extends React.Component {

  Fade.propTypes = {
    visible: PropTypes.bool,
    style: ViewPropTypes.style,  # <= here changed 
    children: PropTypes.any
  };

  ...

}
```

**Why use `ViewPropTypes.style`?**

Because of that is a View Component's style prop.

- View's style prop - [ViewPropTypes.style](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/viewproptypes.html#style)